# Twitter bootstrap table extends outside container on right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a table inside of a Twitter Bootstrap, and when the table has a lot of columns (around 19-20 depending on whats inside them) it extends outside of the .container.

[image: twitter bootstrap table]

The hr tag (gray line underneath table) defines the edges of the .container. The table always extends past it to the right.

**Is it possible to center the table, so that it extends outside the .container on both sides equally?**

Comment: I don't think you can properly center something that hasn't a fixed width (or isn't text-like). Is _counting_ the columns and using the `.span` class possible ? Anyway, multiplying columns may not be the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. It turned that the container's width was smaller than the table's width. If you're using Chrome, the Developer tools are pretty awesome.

I just set it to larger than my table's width, as a temporary fix. My table's width is current 1079px.

```
.container { width: 1200px; }
```

When I increased the table's width to 1132px it started to drift to the right again. I'm going to try decreasing the width of the contents, but it's a difficult problem. Collapsible columns are probably a thing and there's horizontal scroll, but that just seems like more barriers to the data.

Comment: but what about mobile and tablets?

Comment: @EduardoArrudaPimentel I don't have much experience with responsive design besides using that built into bootstrap. But if your table's that wider than your container, try making your container wider. You could set a width specifically for mobile/tablet, or perhaps a percentage, like `.container { width: 80%; }`. Here's your options for width: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp). You might also want to look into decreasing the width of your table somehow.

Comment: What happens if you set the container's `overflow` property to `overflow: scroll`?

Comment: It's not a final solution, but in my case I was able to put the table in a modal. I have a table that renders fine up front, but after clicking 'edit' to change values in the table is when the table would extend outside its container. So I put the editable table in a modal-lg and wrapped it in table-responsive. Now when I shrink the size of the window everything works well with mobile. Not sure that helps your specific problem, but maybe it'll give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.table{table-layout:fixed}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/4889/