# Bootstrap table extends past the container

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a simple table that has a grey background surrounding it, but the lines from my table always extend past the div container. I tried putting it into a form but that didn't help also.

```
<style>
div {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
border-radius: 25px;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-condensed">
<thead>
    <!-- <tr style="max-width: 60%" > -->
    <tr>
        <th>Hour 1</th>
        <th>Hour 2</th>
        <th>Hour 3</th>
        <th>Hour 4</th>
        <th>Hour 5</th>
        <th>Hour 6</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input value="78" type="number" name="grabActual1" id="grabActual1"  placeholder="actual" style="max-width: 60%" ><br><br></td>
        <td><input value="92" type="number" name="grabActual2" id="grabActual2"  placeholder="actual" style="max-width: 60%"><br><br></td> 
        <td><input value="92" type="number" name="grabActual3" id="grabActual3"  placeholder="actual" style="max-width: 60%"><br><br></td> 
        <td><input value="92" type="number" name="grabActual4" id="grabActual4"  placeholder="actual" style="max-width: 60%"><br><br></td>
        <td><input value="92" type="number" name="grabActual5" id="grabActual5"  placeholder="actual" style="max-width: 60%"><br><br></td>
        <td><input value="92" type="number" name="grabActual6" id="grabActual6"  placeholder="actual" style="max-width: 60%"><br><br></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Hour 7</th>
        <th>Hour 8</th>
        <th>Hour 9</th>
        <th>Hour 10</th>
        <th>Hour 11</th>
        <th>Hour 12</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input value="92" type="number" name="grabActual7" id="grabActual7"  placeholder="actual" style="max-width: 60%"><br><br></td> 
        <td><input value="78" type="number" name="grabActual8" id="grabActual8"  placeholder="actual"style="max-width: 60%" ><br><br></td> 
        <td><input value="0" type="number" name="grabActual9" id="grabActual9"  placeholder="actual" style="max-width: 60%" ><br><br></td> 
        <td><input value="0" type="number" name="grabActual10" id="grabActual10"  placeholder="actual" style="max-width: 60%"><br><br></td> 
        <td><input value="0" type="number" name="grabActual11" id="grabActual11"  placeholder="actual" style="max-width: 60%" ><br><br></td> 
        <td><input value="0" type="number" name="grabActual12" id="grabActual12"  placeholder="actual" style="max-width: 60%"><br><br></td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
 </table>

 </div>
```

Things I have tried: (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549149/twitter-bootstrap-table-extends-outside-container-on-right))

```
.container { width: 1200px; }
```

-attempting to change the width of the table.

```
table{
    table-layout: auto;
    width: 500px; 
 }
```

-changing the th/tr/tbody widths to different sizes.

```
th{
     width: 900px;
}
```

I'm just and intern and I asked my supervisor if he knew how to fix it and he couldn't figure it out also because everything we tried to change wouldn't affect it at all. It just stays the same no matter what code I add to it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it legal HTML to have 2 `<tbody` and 2 `<thead>` within the same table? Bad HTML makes for unreliable layout

Comment: Do you mind explaining? I honestly have no idea how else to make it 2 sets of rows. Since this table is the only thing needed on this page, I felt like having 1 long row would make the rest of the page feel empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `table-layout:fixed`

```
.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/4889/

Comment: @Abeasty You may mark it as an answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying the container style differently:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can change the value of the width itself to whatever you see fit.

Comment: Oh thank you! this will be very useful for a problem I was having on my last page actually. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

An update for Bootstrap 5.3 -
You can wrap the element with the bootstrap class `.table` with a div with class `.table-responsive`. This will prevent the table from extending beyond its container and enable horizontal scrolling within the table itself on mobile devices.
An example -

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Link to the documentation- [Bootstrap 5.3 tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/content/tables/#responsive-tables)